# How can I get the Authorization token for the Azure CREST API?

Tags: azure

I want to do something like the following page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/partner-center/develop/get-a-list-of-customers

Therefore, the required request header is as follows.

```html
GET https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers?size=40 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Accept: application/json
MS-RequestId: 3705fc6d-4127-4a87-bdba-9658f73fe019
MS-CorrelationId: b12260fb-82de-4701-a25f-dcd367690645
```

However, I do not know how to obtain the required  here.

Comment: The link you shared has a link to "Partner Centre Authentication" which describes the application registration with Azure AD and relevant C# code to get required token!  https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication

Comment: Thank you! When I wrote the script with reference to this URL, it worked!